Unable to find Inventory Worksheet and Inventory Distribution type while deploying User Event Script In Netsuite
I have written User Event Script for Inventory Worksheet and Inventory While Deploying I am not getting their record type[enterenter image description here image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/HUCXz.png)
I have tried searching resources but havenot get any. Can someone help me
